# Visual Studio, Documentation all methods and classes without their implementation

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, documentation

One of the requirements in a project I need to hand over is a documentation of all the class and methods I use, without their implementation.

I have over 100 methods in my project. I was wondering whether I can automate this process.

**Input:**

```
class A
{
     /// <summary>
     /// Description for SomeMethod.
     /// </summary>
     /// <param name="k">PARAMETER</param>
     /// <returns>PARAMETER + 1</returns>
     public static int SomeMethod(int k)
     {
          return k + 1;
     }

     /// <summary>
     /// Description for AnotherMethod.
     /// </summary>
     public static void AnotherMethod()
     {
          // Code
     }
}
```

*Note: the above is not actual code from my project.*

**Output:**

```
class A
{
     public static int SomeMethod(int k);
     public static void AnotherMethod();
}
```

I fully documented each method and class inside my project. However, I need to prepare a list of all the methods inside each class in the way I presented the desired **Output**.

I'm looking for a tool to speed the whole thing, since I'm not planning on sitting for the next hour to copy and paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various tools to do what you seek and they will extract the method/class/property etc signatures along with your xml comments:

[See Here](http://danielsaidi.wordpress.com/2009/05/25/c-extract-html-documentation-from-xml-comments/)

[And Here](http://www.sandcastledocs.com/)

[And this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641364/c-sharp-documentation-generator)

Comment: I have decided to use Doxygen. Such a great tool, that was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: This answer needs an update, none of the links work anymore.  Makes sense to have a summary of any tools or methods available.